# Let $p(x)=\frac{(|x|+1)^2}{27}$ with $X=-2,-1,0,1,2$. Calculate the probability function and $E[|X|]$, $Var[|X|]$, $Var[2X^2-5X+7]$

Tags: probability

Let $p(x)=\frac{(|x|+1)^2}{27}$ with $X=-2,-1,0,1,2$. Calculate the probability function. $E[X]$, $E[|X|]$, $Var[|X|]$, $E[2X^2-5X+7]$, $Var[2X^2-5X+7]$

**My work**

$p(x=-2)=\frac{9}{27}$
$p(x=-1)=\frac{4}{27}$
$p(x=0)=\frac{1}{27}$
$p(x=1)=\frac{4}{27}$
$p(x=2)=\frac{9}{27}$
$p(x)=0 \iff x\not = X$

Note $p$ is a probability function because:

$p(x_i)\geq 0$

$\sum_{x\in X}p(x)=1$

Moreover,
I know,

$E[X]=\sum_{x\in X}xp(x)$
$Var[X]=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$

Okay, then using this

$E[X]=0$
$E[X^2]=\frac{80}{27}$

Then,

$E[2X^2-5X+7]=2E[X^2]-5E[X]+7E[1]=\frac{160}{27}+7$

> Now, i'm trying to calculate $Var[2X^2-5X+7]$ but i'm stuck here.

And i have other problem.

> How can i calculate $E[|X|]$ and $Var[|X|]$? only consider $X=0,1,2$?

thanks for all!

Comment: I think you don't get what a random variable is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value of $E[f(X)]$ is defined as

$$
E[f(X)] = \sum f(x) p(x)
$$

So

$$
E[|X|] = \sum |x|p(x) = |-2| \cdot \frac {9}{27} + |-1| \cdot \frac{4}{27} + |0| \cdot \frac{1}{27} + |1| \cdot \frac{4}{27} + |2| \cdot \frac{9}{27} = \frac{44}{27}
$$
. 
Now $Var[|X|] = E[|X^2|] - E[|X|]^2 = E[X^2] - E[|X|]^2$. And you already have calculated $E[|X^2|]$ and  $E[|X|]$ so just plug them in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and by the defintion you give me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who came up with this exercise, but i think he doesn't like you.

1. $E[X]=0$,
2. $E[|X|]=2\cdot\frac{9}{27}+\frac{4}{27}+0\cdot\frac{1}{27}+\frac{4}{27}+2\cdot\frac{9}{27}=\frac{44}{27}$,
3. $\text{Var}[|X|]=EX^2-(E[|X|])^2 = \frac{80}{27}-(\frac{44}{27})^2=\frac{224}{729}$,
4. $E[2X^2-5X+7]=2E[X^2]-5E[X]+7=2\cdot\frac{80}{27}-5\cdot0+7 = \frac{349}{27}$,
5. $\text{Var}[X^2-5X+7]$ This one is for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer!